# cvExtractSURF don't work when useProvidedKeypoints = true

Tags: opencv

So, I'm trying to extract some SURF keypoints, but I want to impose these key points! So, I put the last parameter to "true" which is "useProvidedKeypoints".

Also, when I create my Keypoint, I used the default constructor (so some default values there). I only change the point "pt" and the octave that I set to 3.

I'm using the C++ interface with SURF. But I know that the problem is right at cvExtractSURF because I copied that part of the code in mine to help me debug.

When I call that function, with the last parameter set to true, I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /home/widgg/opencv/trunk/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 651
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/widgg/opencv/trunk/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:651: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong!

EDIT:

Here's some code. First how I create the keypoints (I left a couple of informations, like the layer_id stuff, but you get the main idea):

```
for (json_pt_info_vector::iterator b_beg = beg->points.begin(); b_beg != b_end; ++b_beg)
{
  int layer_id = b_beg->layer_id;
  json_point_info_coord &jpic = b_beg->coord;

  jpic.feature_id = features[layer_id].keypoints.size();
  KeyPoint kp;
  kp.octave = 3;
  kp.pt.x = jpic.x;
  kp.pt.y = jpic.y;
  features[layer_id].keypoints.push_back(kp);
}
```

Here's the call to SURF:

```
SURF surf(300, 3, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < nb_img; ++i)
{
  debug_msg("extract_features #4.1");
  cv::detail::ImageFeatures &cdif = features[i];
  Mat gray_image = imread(param.layer_images[i], 0);  // 0 = force to gray scale!

  debug_msg("extract_features #4.2");
  vector<float> descriptors;
  debug_msg("extract_features #4.3");
  surf(gray_image, Mat(), cdif.keypoints, descriptors, true); // MUST BE TRUE TO FORCE THE PROVIDED KEYPOINTS

  debug_msg("extract_features #4.4");
  cdif.descriptors = Mat(descriptors, true).reshape(1, (int)cdif.keypoints.size());
  debug_msg("extract_features #4.5");
  gray_image.release();

  debug_msg("extract_features #4.6");
  images[i] = imread(param.layer_images[i]);  // keep the image open
}
```

It crashes after #4.3 in the debug message!

Hope that helps!

EDIT 2:

I replaced some part by cv::SurfDescriptorExtracter. I replace everything from 4.3 to 4.5 with the following line:

```
 extractor.compute(gray_image, cdif.keypoints, cdif.descriptors);
```

So now, there's still a bug, but it's located somewhere else, not necessary related to this question!

Comment: We need to see our code to help you. If you provide your own vector of cv::Keypoint, you should use (c++ api) cv::DescriptorExtractor object to compute the descriptors.

Comment: how do you use that cv::DescriptorExtractor ? Also, I hope the code that I put helps you a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the call to `surf(gray_image, Mat(), cdif.keypoints, descriptors, true)` even compiles. the `descriptors` argument should be a cv::Mat, not a vector.