# OpenCV: Extract SURF Features from user-defined keypoints

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I want to compute SURF Features from keypoints that I specify.  I am using the Python wrapper of OpenCV.  The following is the code I am trying to use, but I cannot find a working example anywhere.

```
surf = cv2.SURF()
keypoints, descriptors = surf.detect(np.asarray(image[:,:]),None,useProvidedKeypoints = True)
```

How can I specify the keypoints to be used by this function?

Similar, unanswered, question:
[cvExtractSURF don't work when useProvidedKeypoints = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144106/cvextractsurf-dont-work-when-useprovidedkeypoints-true?rq=1)

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html)

Comment: Did you mange to get it working in the end ?

Comment: I did and I even posted the answer here, but I just noticed that it was deleted for some reason.  Strange.  Anyway, you can use [Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas/) to do this, or perhaps check out some of the other answers that have been posted in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

**Try using cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create for that.**

For instance, in the following code I am using pylab, but you can get the message ;)

It computes the keypoints using GFTT, and then uses the SURF descriptor and the Brute force matching.
The output of each code part is show as header.

---

```
%pylab inline
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('./img/nail.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imshow(gray,  cmap=cm.gray)
```

Output is something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eOTe.png

(For this example I will cheat and use the same image to get the keypoints and descriptors).

```
img1 = gray
img2 = gray
detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("GFTT")
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
matcher = pt1=(int(k1[m.queryIdx].pt[0]),int(k1[m.queryIdx].pt[1]))("FlannBased")

# detect keypoints
kp1 = detector.detect(img1)
kp2 = detector.detect(img2)

print '#keypoints in image1: %d, image2: %d' % (len(kp1), len(kp2))
```

## keypoints in image1: 1000, image2: 1000

```
# descriptors
k1, d1 = descriptor.compute(img1, kp1)
k2, d2 = descriptor.compute(img2, kp2)

print '#Descriptors size in image1: %s, image2: %s' % ((d1.shape), (d2.shape))
```

## Descriptors size in image1: (1000, 64), image2: (1000, 64)

```
# match the keypoints
matches = matcher.match(d1,d2)

# visualize the matches
print '#matches:', len(matches)
dist = [m.distance for m in matches]

print 'distance: min: %.3f' % min(dist)
print 'distance: mean: %.3f' % (sum(dist) / len(dist))
print 'distance: max: %.3f' % max(dist)
```

## matches: 1000

distance: min: 0.000

distance: mean: 0.000

distance: max: 0.000

```
# threshold: half the mean
thres_dist = (sum(dist) / len(dist)) * 0.5 + 0.5

# keep only the reasonable matches
sel_matches = [m for m in matches if m.distance < thres_dist]

print '#selected matches:', len(sel_matches)
```

## selected matches: 1000

```
#Plot
h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]
view = zeros((max(h1, h2), w1 + w2, 3), uint8)
view[:h1, :w1, 0] = img1
view[:h2, w1:, 0] = img2
view[:, :, 1] = view[:, :, 0]
view[:, :, 2] = view[:, :, 0]

for m in sel_matches:
    # draw the keypoints
    # print m.queryIdx, m.trainIdx, m.distance
    color = tuple([random.randint(0, 255) for _ in xrange(3)])
    pt1=(int(k1[m.queryIdx].pt[0]),int(k1[m.queryIdx].pt[1]))
    pt2=(int(k2[m.queryIdx].pt[0]+w1),int(k2[m.queryIdx].pt[1]))
    cv2.line(view,pt1,pt2,color)
```

Output is something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CqrJ.png

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the source code of the Python bindings correctly, the "keypoints" argument that is present in the C++ interface is never used in the Python bindings. So I hazard that it's not possible to do what you are trying to do with the current bindings. A possible solution would be to write your own binding. I know it's not the answer you were hoping...

Comment: I was starting to suspect the same actually... I have started looking into using a Python library for SURF, such as [Python Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to write your own binding to your own custom function though.

Comment: Author of mahotas here: mahotas can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how this can be done with the before-mentioned `Mahotas`:

```
import mahotas
from mahotas.features import surf
import numpy as np


def process_image(imagename):
    '''Process an image and returns descriptors and keypoints location'''
    # Load the images
    f = mahotas.imread(imagename, as_grey=True)
    f = f.astype(np.uint8)

    spoints = surf.dense(f, spacing=12, include_interest_point=True)
    # spoints includes both the detection information (such as the position
    # and the scale) as well as the descriptor (i.e., what the area around
    # the point looks like). We only want to use the descriptor for
    # clustering. The descriptor starts at position 5:
    desc = spoints[:, 5:]
    kp = spoints[:, :2]

    return kp, desc
```